# Why can't I use cmd key to change languages for a single character?

Tags: keyboard, language

On my macbook keyboard I have two languages - Hebrew and US. On 'keyboard viewer' I see that clicking and holding the cmd should temporarly switch to the other language (instead of cmd+space and then cmd+space again to go back), but that doesn't seem to work. any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

Cmd isn’t mormally used for making characters in macos -- instead it is employed for menu shortcuts and other purposes. You can use caps lock to switch to the US keyboard for character input if you set that option in system preferences/keyboard/input sources.

If you use the input source named "Hebrew" , then you should be able to get Latin characters by pressing caps lock (without actually switching to the US layout).

The input source named "Hebrew PC" will generate Latin characters when you hold down the Shift key, but only upper case.

Comment: Thank you Tom, but what I'm looking for is a way to avoid the need to switch to English and then switch back to Hebrew just for typing one or a few characters. In Windows it is possible by clicking and holding the ctrl key. On Mac it *seems like* it should be possible based on the Keyboard Viewer - There once you have two languages installed, clicking and holding the cmd key switches all characters to the other languages, but that happens only in the keyboard viewer.

Comment: Keyboard Viewer just can't be used as a guide to character input with Control or Command, because MacOS does not use those modifiers for that purpose.  To switch scripts by just holding down a key, you would need to make a custom keyboard layout with Ukelele or Karabiner.